# Avoid rerender on several firebase snapshots with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, use-effect

Problem: I have a useEffect, where I collect data from 4 different firebase collections. This makes the site (re)render 4 times. Question is how do I avoid this? I get that its rerendering for every setState right, but unsure on how to avoid this. Im assuming I will have to use an async function of some sorts?

Im quite new to async functions, I thought on maybe using promise -> resolve on each onSnap function, but wont this break the listener detachment?

Code following:

```
 useEffect(() => {

        const unsubInstruments = DB.collection(`organizations/${window.localStorage.getItem(OrgKey)}/assets/instrumentarchive/items`)
        const unsubUniforms = DB.collection(`organizations/${window.localStorage.getItem(OrgKey)}/assets/uniformarchive/items`)
        const unsubOtherAssets = DB.collection(`organizations/${window.localStorage.getItem(OrgKey)}/assets/other_assets/items`)

        const unsubAssetsCollection = DB.collection(`organizations/${window.localStorage.getItem(OrgKey)}/assets`)

        const getCollectionSizes = async () => {

            const assetsSize = () => {
                unsubAssetsCollection.onSnapshot((snap) => {
                    let assetsSize = snap.size
                    setAssetsSize(assetsSize)
                })
                return () => unsubInstruments()
            }

            const instrumentsSize = () => {
                unsubInstruments.onSnapshot((snap) => {
                    let instruments = snap.size
                    setInstruments(instruments)
                })
                return () => unsubInstruments()
            }

            const uniformsSize = () => {
                unsubUniforms.onSnapshot((snap) => {
                    let uniforms = snap.size
                    setUniforms(uniforms)
                })
                return () => unsubUniforms()
            }

            const otherAssetsSize = () => {
                unsubOtherAssets.onSnapshot((snap) => {
                    let otherAssets = snap.size
                    setOtherAssets(otherAssets)
                })
                return () => unsubOtherAssets()
            }

            assetsSize()
            instrumentsSize()
            uniformsSize()
            otherAssetsSize()

        }

        getCollectionSizes()
    }, [])
```

Comment: You set your data in different states of your component, doesn't it? I mean calling functions like `setUniforms`, `setInstruments` and so on.

Comment: So I should rather have one state like this: `const [state, setState] = usestate({
instruments : "",
uniforms : ""
}) ` And then set the data to this?

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you have only one state then rerendering will be called once.

Answer (score 1):

So as the comments say, the answer is to not use state like I have done, but rather have one state, with the state variables inside this.